# Tomcat (7&8): use outgoing http proxy for certain servers

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, proxy

We're mostly using services from our internal network and for outgoing services out service provider has set up a proxy. Our configurations are in Tomcat's setenv.sh currently and are like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS" -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.of_some_sort.de -Dhttp.proxyPort=800 "
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS" -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=our_server.de\|*.another.de\|*.something_else.de\|*.our_stuff.de"
```

It appears that connections we want to go through the proxy do go that way, but also those that should be caught by the nonProxyHosts are going through it, resulting in troubles. The error we got from these requests is 403 forbidden.

We are not certain whether these might affect the situation:

- our internal address service assigns addresses that include ports, for example http://this_is.our_server.de:80/
- Many of our services utilize Spring framework and its service classes

Strangely enough our internal address service is found but addresses (even in the same domain) returned by it result in 403 forbidden:

```
 Error in accessing remote service https://service.our_stuff.de:443/service_path/OurService Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [https://service.our_stuff.de:443/service_path/OurService]; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: Did not receive successful HTTP response: status code = 403, status message = [Forbidden]
```

In fact we want to use the proxy for about 2 to 4 outside addresses so if it were possible, we would only configure the proxy the other way around, only defining those few addresses where it should be used, but apparently it's not possible, am I right?

Any insight into this shall be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that we had a faulty http invoker bean in our framework and it is being fixed. So if you encounter problems with Spring service calls being routed wrong, check whether your software is parsing the proxy settings by itself.

Sorry to bother you :)